# How to use i18next to localize attribute (for jQuery UI tooltip using title in my case)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, localization, jquery-ui-tooltip, i18next

I'm checking if we could use i18next with our project.

I found out one issue with jQuery UI tooltips : jQuery UI gets tooltip content from title attribute and i18next localizes element content with data-i18n attribute.

http://i18next.com/pages/doc_templates.html has links to gists handling jQuery UI dialog/button, do we have to do something similar or is there some other option?

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="#" ng-i18next="[title]hello">This is a link.</a>`

=> translates *hello* and sets it as the title

Read [here](https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next#attributes).

Comment: not working can you please describe this or add plunker

Comment: do you use $scope.hello ? 
would be then `<a href="#" ng-i18next="[title]{{hello}}">This is a link.</a>`

Answer (score -1):

```
$("SelectedElement").attr("data-i18n", "[title]YOUR_KEY").i18n();
```

try this